# Subquery for max ID numbers

Tags: sql, ms-access, group-by, max

I have a query that I am trying to filter for a report.  Each addressID can have multiple jobs and each job can have multiple elements to it.

Basically I am trying to get the maximum jobID for each addressID, but I want to get each element of the job.

The current Query results are:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+
| AddressID | JobID | Cost   |
+-----------+-------+--------+
| 326       | 328   | £52.50 |
| 327       | 329   | £55.13 |
| 328       | 330   | £57.88 |
| 329       | 331   | £60.78 |
| 329       | 331   | £63.81 |
| 330       | 332   | £67.00 |
| 330       | 332   | £70.36 |
| 330       | 332   | £73.87 |
| 330       | 332   | £77.57 |
| 330       | 333   | £57.75 |
| 330       | 333   | £60.64 |
| 330       | 333   | £63.67 |
| 330       | 333   | £66.85 |
| 331       | 334   | £70.20 |
| 331       | 334   | £73.71 |
| 331       | 335   | £77.39 |
| 331       | 336   | £81.26 |
| 331       | 336   | £85.32 |
| 331       | 336   | £89.59 |
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

And I am trying to get:

```
+-----------+-------+--------+
| AddressID | JobID | Cost   |
+-----------+-------+--------+
| 326       | 328   | £52.50 |
| 327       | 329   | £55.13 |
| 328       | 330   | £57.88 |
| 329       | 331   | £60.78 |
| 329       | 331   | £63.81 |
| 330       | 333   | £57.75 |
| 330       | 333   | £60.64 |
| 330       | 333   | £63.67 |
| 330       | 333   | £66.85 |
| 331       | 336   | £81.26 |
| 331       | 336   | £85.32 |
| 331       | 336   | £89.59 |
+-----------+-------+--------+
```

I had been looking at SELECT TOP 1 to isolate the MAX JobID, but ended up limiting the query to just 1 entry.

Currently tweaking this subquery, but still not sure I'm on the right track:

```
(SELECT Max(vusearch.JobID) FROM vuSearch AS T WHERE PAID = vuSearch.AddressID GROUP BY AddressID)
```

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 4):

Here is one method:

```
select v.*
from vusearch as v
where v.JobId = (select max(v2.JobId)
                 from vusearch as v2
                 where v2.AddressId = v.AddressId
                );
```

Comment: Thanks for that Gordon.  Would this go in as a subquery under JobID in design view?  I am getting an error 'You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved word in the main query's FROM clause.Revise the SELECT statement of the subquery to request only one field.

Comment: @GlibGibon . . . The subquery, as written, returns one row (because it is an aggregation query with no `group by`) and has only one field.  That error does not make sense.

Comment: I've checked and rechecked.  I'm using Access2013.  The subquery I am putting into the criteria section of the JobID field.  When I look at the the SQL view, the code is at the end of the query (in the where clause).  Am I putting this in the right place?  Joins within the main query wouldn't impact this as I am only looking at the one table would it?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get it fixed - I probably hadn't provided enough information as I was trying to keep my explanation simple.

Many thanks for your help Gordon

((vuSearch.PDID) IN ( (SELECT Max(v2.PDID) FROM vuSearch AS v2 GROUP BY v2.PAID)))